# ¿Cómo fuciona Thread.sleep() de java?

Tags: java

Apenas estoy viendo hilos en java y me entro la siguiente duda con resecto a  la  `Thread.sleep(double millis)`. Es decir, ¿Cuando se llama para hacer esperar al hilo en cuestión los demás hilos siguen su ejecución o tienen que esperar hasta que `millis` llegue a cero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Funcion y proposito de sleep()**

`Thread.sleep()` puedes verlo como si se tratara de un `setTiemOut()` como lo seria en otros lenguajes como lo es javascript. Realmente el sleep sirve para lo que dice su nombre, dormir un hilo por x cantidad de tiempo ininterrumpido hasta que el conteo llegue a 0 sin excepciones. El hilo en java puede ser dormido de 2 formas, una es con el `sleep()` que tu ya mencionaste que como parametro recibe una x cantidad de milisegundos para tiempo y la otra es `wait()` que en este caso a pesar de que también puede ser utilizado con mili segundos no es lo mas indicado (principalmente porque tiene otra función mas importante). En este caso `wait()` sirve para poder dormir el hilo por un tiempo indefinido que podría llevarte a dejarlo en dicho estado por todo el tiempo de ejecución del programa y que solo despierte bajo ciertas circunstancias (el `wait()` despierta con un `notify()` o un `notifyAll()`) y es asi como obtendrias dos formas de dormir un hilo en java pero con diferentes funciones para cada caso.

**RESUMEN**

- `sleep()` dormirá el hilo por x cantidad de tiempo y todos los demás hilos corren independientemente.
- `wait()` detiene la ejecución de un hilo hasta que es despertado por un `notify()` o `notifyAll()` pero el resto de hilos siguen corriendo independientemente.

> Fuentes de consulta: [Esperando datos: wait() y notify()](http://www.chuidiang.org/java/hilos/wait_y_notify.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ahora puedo verlo de una manera diferente y mejor. :D

Comment: No hay de que agradecer, cualquier otra duda con el tema no dudes en preguntar :)